# How to search for files faster in Sublime Text 3

Tags: search, sublimetext3, workflow

Right now I do <kbd>⌘t</kbd> then scroll through autocomplete, or start typing the name (but half the time it doesn't find it).

Sublime doesn't find a file in many cases. For example, I typically have all my files called `index.<ext>` nested inside some folder. So I might have:

```
my/long/directory/structure/index.js
my/long/directory/structure2/index.js
my/long/directory/structure3/index.js
my/long/directory/structure.../index.js
my/long/directory/structuren/index.js
my/long/directory/index.js
my/long/directory2/index.js
my/long/directory.../index.js
my/long/directoryn/index.js
my/long/index.js
my/index.js
...
```

But in sublime you have to search for an **exact path**. I can't search this:

```
my directory index
```

And get results for directory, directory2, directory..., directoryn, I just get empty results because there is not `my/directory`. I can't remember the full folder path most of the time, so it takes a lot of effort to do so and I end up just navigating in the sidebar to find the file which takes some time.

Wondering if there is a better/faster way of doing this. Basically searching for a file by snippets/keywords of the complete path. So `m dir` would return `my/long/directory`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you do ***not*** have to search for an *exact path*; anywhere that Sublime provides you a list of items to select from and a text entry, fuzzy matching is in play. In your example searching just for `idx` will narrow down the list to all items that have those characters in that order, even if they're not adjacent to each other.

The entries show you visually how they're matching up, and there's a fairly sophisticated system behind the scenes that decides which characters make the best matches (relative to some hidden scoring algorithm):

[image: Goto Anything One]

In addition to this you can use multiple space separated terms to filter down the list. Each term is applied to the list of items resulting from the prior term, so they don't need to be provided in the same order as they appear in the file names.

This helps with searches where you know generally the name of the file, and from there can further drill down on segments of the path or other terms that will help narrow things down:

[image: Goto Anything Two]

Something to note here is that as seen in these images, the folder structure is `my/long/directory/structure`, but the names of the files as seen in the panel don't include the `my/` at the start.

In cases where your project contains only one top level folder, that folder isn't presented in the names of the files. Presumably this is because it's common to every file and thus not going to be a useful filter. As such trying to use `my` in the search field will return no matches unless one of the files has an `m` and a `y` somewhere in their filenames.

This isn't the case if there are multiple top level folders; in that case Sublime will include the root folder in the names of the files presented because now it's required to be able to distinguish between files in the different folders:

[image: Goto Anything Three]

In addition to this, note that for any given filter text you enter in a panel, Sublime remembers the full text of the item that you selected while that filter text was being used, and uses that in it's scoring to prioritize the matches the next time you search in the same panel. The next time you search with the same term, Sublime will automatically pre-select the item that you picked last time under the theory that you probably want it again.

The search terms and their matches are saved in the session file and in your project's `sublime-workspace` files, so as you move from window to window and project to project you're essentially training Sublime how to find the files that you want.

My advice would be to try and flip your thinking a little bit. In my opinion the power of the fuzzy matching algorithm works best when you try to find files in a more organic way than trying to replicate the path entirely.

Instead, I would throw a few characters from the name of the file that I'm trying to find first, and then add another term that filters on some part of the path that will disambiguate things more; a term of `idx s1` in this example immediately finds the two `index.js` files that are contained in `structure1` folders, for example.

In a more real world example the names of the folders might contain the names of the components that they're a part of or something else that is providing a logical structure to the code, so you might do `idx con` to pull the `index.js` from the `controller` folder or `idx mod` to find the one in the `model` folder, and so on.

Regarding a better/faster way to do this I don't think there is one, at least in the general case. Sublime inherently knows every file that's in your project as a part of indexing all of the files to power other features such as  `Goto Symbol` and it uses file watchers to detect changes to the structure of the open folders.

Anything else, including a third party plugin or package, would need to first do a redundant file scan to accumulate the list of files and would also have to replicate the file watching that Sublime is already doing in order to know when things change.